# How to compare updated entity with old entity and store only the updated values in the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-rest

I'm working with Spring Boot + Rest + Jpa .So if a user edits any of the  employee entity (empId, salary, age, location, role, experience) columns mapped to the employee table, I should track the old and new changes and enter into a audit table, with the column changed.

```
public EmployeeEntity update(int empId, EmployeeEntity employeeEntity ) {

    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EmployeeEntity beforeObj = em.find(EmployeeEntity .class,empId );

    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.merge(employeeEntity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return employeeEntity;
}
```

So now I have entities with beforeObj (the employee entity with old values) and employeeEntity (the updated values), so for eg is only salary and location is being updated, I have to track those and update in a audit table . Need to do plain simple than using Envers or any other JPA tools ,since only minimal transaction can happen.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "EMP_NO")
private int EMP_NO;

@Column(name = "SALARY_VAL")
private int SALARY_VA;

@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME")
private String ROLE_NAME;

@Column(name = "EXPERIENCE")
private int EXPERIENCE;

@Column(name = "LOCATION")
private String LOCATION;

// Getters and Setters
```

Insights needed for the same.

Comment: You need to be aware if the object (item being edited) is connected or disconnected.  See here for disconnected hints : https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach

Comment: you can use a dto

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "old" or "new" object when working with JPA. You typically retrieve an object from the database through the `EntityManager`, modify it, and commit the transaction (upon which the current state of the object in question is persisted to the database.)

From what I can tell you have two options here:

1) Create database triggers that populate the audit table on updates to your employee-table. If you do this, keep the audit-table far away from your JPA-mappings, let it live in the database only.

2) Create a change-log entity for your employee.

```
public enum EmployeeChangeType {
    SALARY_UPDATED,
    LOCATION_UPDATED
}

@Entity
public class Change {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private EmployeeChangeType changeType;

    private String oldValue;

    private String newValue;

    private String changedByUser;

    //...
}

@Entity
public class Employee {
    //...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Change> changes = new ArrayList<>();

    //...
    public void updateSalary(final Integer newSalary, final String updatedBy) {
        changes.add(new Change(EmployeeChangeType.SALARY_UPDATED, SALARY_VAL, newSalary, updatedBy));
        SALARY_VAL = newSalary;
    }
```

Not a complete example, but hopefully you get the picture..

Also, there is no need to use all-caps variable names in entities, the whole point of JPA is to separate your database design from your Java design.

Update: 
Bonus solution:
In some cases, using revisions of your entities. Then, updates to the entity will result in a new row in the database. In my opinion this is not a very pretty way of solving it, and should be used with caution..

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Lazy
    @OneToOne
    private Employee lastVersion;

    //some identifier that is common for all versions of employee
    private Integer employeeNumber;

    public Employee(final Employee currentVersion) {
        //copy all fields from currentVersion to this, except id
        this.lastVersion = currentVersion;
    }
    //...
}
```

You typically do this:

```
 final Employee currentVersion = employeeRepo.getCurrentVersion(employeeId);
 final Employee newVersion = new Employee(currentVersion);
 //do changes to employee
 employeeRepo.persist(newVersion);
```

It kind of strikes me as misuse of JPA, but might be applicable to some cases..

Comment: Appreciate the effort for answering .

Comment: I'm interested in this question as well. Does that mean if I want to track every field, I should consider having `oldValue` and `newValue` as object (to handle string, double and such) and having the changeType enumeration list all fields ? For the`OneToMany` relationship, I assume it's rather about `add` and `remove` operation. Am I correct ?

Comment: The reason it is `String` is that you have to map it to a certain column in the database. And since you cant put a `String` into an `int`, you have to use `String` and then some string representation of whatever the datatype is. Note that this is meant for documentation mainly, other than perhaps showing a change log you don't really do anything with the information. For collections you typically log add and remove, yes. There is one other way of solving this, through versions/revisions of the same object. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although @Tobb has already submitted a solid answer, there is another path you could take in cases where changes to Employee records need to be approved before actually going live.  You could implement your "audit" table as "Employee History" where "Employee History" has every column that "Employee" does plus columns to track who changed what data and when. You can use "expired timestamp" and "active timestamp" columns to track which "history" record should match the active record in the real "Employee" table.

Then when a regular user makes a change to an Employee record, the changed record is only saved to the "Employee History" table, and an "audit request" can be triggered to alert the person who needs to review and approve the change so the change can be written to the real "Employee" table.  When the reviewer does the audit, the "history" table will contain both the old unchanged Employee History record (the one with NULL expired timestamp, and the most recent active timestamp) and the new proposed change Employee History record (the one with both expired and active timestamps NULL).  After the reviewer does the audit, the old unchanged Employee History record will have a current expired timestamp, and the new updated Employee History record will have a NULL expired timestamp and the most recent active timestamp.  The new updated Employee History record will also match the updated associated Employee record.

Comment: Appreciate the effort for answering .

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Hibernate documentation about events in JPA and Hibernate:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

There you will see how to implement that in a generic way.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate the effort for answering .